# Memory altered unexpectedly only on gcc?

Tags: c++

In the following code, the memory address of the `char* d` is altered after 100ms and I did nothing to alter it. Can someone please explain where in the following code is an undefined behavior?

This behavior is only visible on gcc 4.8.2, not on visual studio 2012.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class state_p
{
public:
    unsigned char* state;

    void init(unsigned char* state_in)
    {
        state = state_in;
    }
};

void state_link(unsigned char* &state)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        state_p s;
        s.init(state+184*i);
    }
}

void go_sleep(unsigned int ms)
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(ms));
}

class main_class
{
private:
    char *d;
    unsigned s;
    char* a;

    void core()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            cout << "A_CORE: " << (void*)d << "\n";
        }
    }

public:
    main_class() {}

    main_class(char *di)
    {
        d = di;
        boost::thread start_core_thread(&main_class::core, this);
    }
};

void show(unsigned int &i)
{
    cout << i;
    go_sleep(100000000);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char *state = (unsigned char*)calloc(3072, sizeof(char));

    char st = 100;
    main_class main_c;
    main_c = main_class(&st);

    state_link(state);

    go_sleep(100);
    unsigned int i = 0;
    show(i);
}
```

Output:

```
A_CORE: 0x186a0
A_CORE: 0x186a0
A_CORE: 0x186a0
A_CORE: 0x186a0
A_CORE: 0x186a0
A_CORE: 0x186a0
A_CORE: 0x186a0
A_CORE: 0x186a0
A_CORE: 0
A_CORE: 0
A_CORE: 0
A_CORE: 0
```

Comment: what is your output?

Comment: @Chris Maes: I added the output

Comment: What are `start_core_thread` and `show`? Also, is the output you copied the full output, or the last 12 lines of the full output, or 12 lines selected from the middle of the full output?

Comment: @ChrisCulter: `start_core_thread` is a local variable. `show` is the function defined just before `main`.

Comment: What do you mean what they are? The output, is huge due to `go_sleep(100000000);`. What I posted are some lines from the middle of the output. The actual output is `A_CORE: 0x186a0` for 100ms and then `A_CORE: 0` till the program exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
main_c = main_class(&st);
```

you create and destroy a temporary `main_class`, copying it to `main_c`. Here:

```
boost::thread start_core_thread(&main_class::core, this);
```

you bind a pointer to that temporary to the thread. The thread keeps accessing it after it's destroyed, giving undefined behaviour. In particular, if the storage for the temporary is reused for another object, you might well see the value change.

If you were to initialise the non-temporary object directly:

```
main_class main_c(&st);
```

then you should be back in the realm of well-defined behaviour. You might consider making the class uncopyable, to prevent this error.

You should also explicitly detach the thread, or keep hold of it as a class member to join later. Destroying a thread object without joining or detaching it is deprecated in Boost, and forbidden in the standard library.

Comment: Thanks you are the best, I wasted 10 hours on this! I understand how to fix it now, but I still don't understand why I should't copy the class. Can you please explain this?

Comment: @SpeedCoder: Because, when you create the temporary, the constructor passes `this` - a pointer to the class being created - to the thread. Copying the object doesn't update the thread's pointer - it's still accessing the old object. In this case, the temporary is destroyed after assignment, leaving the thread with an invalid pointer.

Comment: Thanks, I bet if I ask my c++ professor he won't know this!